# Show that there is a bijection between the collection of all algebraic sets and the collection of all radical ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to use the Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to show that there is a bijection between the collection $ X $ of all algebraic sets of $ \mathbb{A}^n(k) $ and the collection $ R $ of all radical ideals of $ k[x_1, \cdots, x_n] $, where $ k $ is an algebraically closed field. I was thinking that maybe 
\begin{align*}
\phi:R&\to X\\
I&\mapsto V(I)
\end{align*}
could do the trick since I can show that $ \phi $ is surjective. However, I don't think it is a injection since $ V(I)=V(J) $ does not imply $ I=J $. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better map, or an other way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I$ and $J$ are radical ideals then $V(I)=V(J)$ **does** imply $I=J$.

In general, if $I(X)$ is the ideal of functions vanishing on $X\subseteq
\Bbb A^n(k)$ (sorry two uses of $I$) then $I(V(I))=\sqrt I$ (this is one form of the Nullstellensatz) and so $V(I)=V(J)$ implies $I(V(I))=I(V(J))$
implies $\sqrt I=\sqrt J$. So if $I$ and $J$ are radical we get
$I=\sqrt I=\sqrt J=J$.